# Test whether a set of samples follow laplace distribution

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, matlab

I have a set of samples from a random variable, is there any method so that I can confirm/check to know whether they follow a laplace distribution in an statistically rigorous way?

I am very new to statistics and would really be grateful if you could at least point me towards some litrature.

Thanks

Comment: Is this with unknown scale and location?

Comment: actually i am interested in both, in my case I might have to estimate location and scale.

Comment: I *never* seen "real" data that follows a Laplace distribution. Just curious, what kind of data is it? (I you can tell, that is...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a quantile-quantile plot (q-q plot) as a first step to see if your data appears to follow a Laplace distribution.  You would basically plot the theoretical quantiles of the Laplace distirbution against the quantiles of you samples and if the points lie on the line $x=y$ then you would conclude that it seems reasonable that your sample comes from the Laplace distribution.

Here is the Wikipedia reference for more info:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot